# Autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity in time series regression

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm running time series regressions with a small dataset (about 50 obs and < 10 variables) and wondering about correcting for auto correlation and heteroskedasticity in the same regression model. I came across past literature suggesting that it is best to correct for autocorrelation first and then heteroskedasticity: thus, in a regression (where Durbin-Watson statistic was .79 and the hettest was significant and chi2=6.34) I tried to correct for autocorrelation using <prais x1 x2 x3, corc> and then ran <regress x1 x2 x3, vce(robust)> to correct for heteroskedasticity. I was wondering if this is correct? Thank you for any help you can give.